# Vi editor: deleting a portion of a line

Tags: vim

Consider the following line of python code:

`columns = ["registered","casual","counts", "workingday", "month", "dteday"]`

I often need to remove one or more strings from such a list. What is the most efficient way to do this? I usually move cursor to beginning of first word and use visual mode to highlight and then delete the relevant strings. This is pretty inefficient as the quotation marks render the `e` command less effective; is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I would move to the starting quote, then `df,`, or `dt]` if it's the last.

Comment: @roaima they're from the original, and [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html#tag_20_152_13_76). There's no need for another answer, this shouldn't become a `vi` treatise ;-) especially since there are so many things to say about it (that moving commands can take a count, that `f` could be repeated with `[cnt];`, that changing commands could be repeated with `[cnt].`, etc, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how your editor has been set up you could use either `dw` or `dW`. The second will always work if you have whitespace after each comma.

Lowercase `w` represents a word, as distinct from punctuation.  Uppercase `W` represents a sequence of characters until whitespace.

You can also use constructs such as `d/` followed by a comma and enter, which will delete from the cursor to the first matching point.

Comment: `dW` will not work if the literal strings contain whitespaces, eg `"registered user"`.

Answer (score 1):

For simple contents like your example, you can use the fact that a whole argument (including the trailing comma) is a single [`:help WORD`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#WORD). For complex arguments, that quickly falls apart, and alternatives like `f{char}` or `/{pattern}` are cumbersome. *Visual mode* is the built-in answer, for iterative refinement of the text. If you want something better, you need a plugin that can understand the syntax of arguments. I can recommend [sideways.vim](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/sideways.vim) as a powerful and generic one that both offers selection of (inner / outer) arguments, as well as the capability to reorder them.